# Geometric interpretation of inner product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inner-products

Consider space $\mathcal{S}=\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Let $\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}\in\mathcal{S}$. The inner product between $\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}$ is defined as (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product)

\begin{equation}
<\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}> = trace(\mathbf{Y}^{T}\mathbf{X}^{})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{X}_{i,j}\mathbf{Y}_{i,j} 
\end{equation}

In $\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^3$, "Inner Products" give us a notion of "angle" between the two vectors i-e

\begin{equation}
<\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}> = \|\mathbf{x}\|\|\mathbf{y}\| cos(\theta) 
\end{equation}

I am wondering how to extend this geometric interpretation to matrices? What does it mean for two matrices to be "aligned". Does it mean their singular vectors are *aligned*?

Comment: The inner product on $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ basically makes it isometric to $\Bbb R^{n^2}$; thus two matrices are *aligned* if and only if one is a multiple of the other. For matrices, you can define an angle between matrices using the same formula as for vectors (this works in any inner product space thanks to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality), but I don't know if there's any thing interesting to say about it.